# GDM3 disable specific users

Tags: 19.04, gdm

Ubuntu 19.04

In gdm3 there is no `/etc/gdm3/gdm.schema`

Also there is no `Exclude` key in `/usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas`

Also adding:

```
[greeter]
Exclude=targetuser
```

... in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` has no effect (after restarting of course)

So the question is, what is the secret sauce to disable a certain (not all) user from showing up in the user list?

Thanks